# Can video autoplay on mobile devices

Tags: android, html, youtube, video-streaming, jwplayer

I had always heard this was a disabled feature on all mobile devices but I was corrected earlier today when I went to youtube.com from my android phone and lo and behold, it played on its own. Is this possible with jwplayer? Is it possible on any other player other than youtube?I've tried this in the past using all the built in features as well as some javascript workarounds such as clicking the play button when the page has loaded. 
I understand bandwidth usage but what about streaming media sites that users KNOW they are about to watch a video.. after-all that's why they went to that site.

Comment: Doesn't `JWPlayerView.play()` work? You can even use `MediaPlayer` and play it programatically

Comment: Not automatically. The play button still needs to be manually clicked.

Comment: http://qa.jwplayer.com/support-demos/ios-autoplay.html

Answer (score 0):

I never have seen that a video is opened automatically in mobiles or tablets.

I just tried myselft with youtube, and it does not play automatically if you use the web browser. However It does play automatically if you open the video with the youtube app.

Can you provide a link where this is happening? and the details of where are you testing this (browser, device,...) ?

Comment: What phone are you on? I noticed on my older Galaxy s4 active (android 4.3) youtube.com will only play manually but on my Galaxy s6 edge (android 5.1.1) youtube.com autoplays using the stock chrome browser and stock android browser.

Comment: Interesting.... I tried in an Android 5.0 and youtube does not autoplay.not in firefox neither in chrome.

Comment: Maybe google guys found a workaround but if you look at the documentation of jwplayer and flowplayer you can read that autoplay in mobile devices is not supported. [link](http://www.jwplayer.com/html5/) [link](https://flowplayer.org/docs/known-issues.html). And as they said there are good reason to avoid the autoplay (limit data and battery usage)

Answer (score 0):

Some Android devices may allow it to autostart. iPad may allow it. iPad does allow inline videos to play one at a time.